# Why does {{undefined + number}} return number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS project. I noticed that the following expression returns a number.

In the view, `{{undefined + 10}}` will output 10.

In JavaScript, `undefined + 10` will output **NaN**.

Why is this behavior different in a view?

Comment: I can suggest, that `undefined` values are just ignored inside interpolation, so `{{undefined + 10}}` is actually {{ + 10 }}. But it's just my suggestion.

Comment: Btw. it does return a `string` and not a `number`.

Comment: javascript is mostly string based, so undefined is variable is 'string empty' and what is not a number.

Comment: @lin Type returned is NaN not string. As you mentioned above

Comment: @anu `{{undefined + 10}}` get be parsed and returned as a string.

Comment: @lin It returns as NaN not string. Kindly check once again.  I had run test cases and then only posting here.

Comment: In general, asking "why" questions about JavaScript type coercion semantics is going on a fool's errand. "Why" implies that a principled approach was taken and that we can work backwards from observations to the principles underlying them.  But in JS, (as Gary Bernhardt points out) `[]+[]` is "", `[]+{}` is object, `{}+[]` is 0 and `{}+{}` is `NaN`. WAT? The rules are sufficiently arcane, arbitrary and inconsistent that trying to apply principles is absurdly difficult.

Comment: My question was mainly about AngularJS behavior. With Alexandru & Steffen explanations, it's ok for me!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That's the advantage of interpolation.

**Interpolation** markup with embedded expressions is used by AngularJS to provide data-binding to text nodes and attribute values.

If the interpolated value is not a String, it is computed as follows:

- **undefined and null are converted to '' (empty string)**
- if the value is an object that is not a Number, Date or Array, `$interpolate` looks for a custom `toString()` function on the object, and uses that.
- if the above doesn't apply, `JSON.stringify` is used.

During runtime the compiler uses the `$interpolate` service to see if text nodes and element attributes contain interpolation markup with embedded expressions.

Also, the angular compiler use an `interpolateDirective` and registers watchers in order to listen for model changes. That's the process of digest cycle.

Read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) to understand how interpolation works.

> Why `{{'' == +Infinity}}` returns true ?

In AngularJS, `$interpolate` service evaluates `+Infinity` to `0` value.

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('Controller', ['$injector', function($injector) {

}]);
setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    {{+Infinity}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the expression remain `{{0==''}}`.

Why `0==''` is evaluated to `true` ?

The left side is of type `Number`. The right side is of type `String`.

In this case, the right operand is coerced to the type Number:

```
0 == Number('') => 0 == 0,
```

which is evaluated to `true` boolean value.

Here is applied [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3).

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the
>   comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't know interpolation! You've been too fast, can't accept your answer before 5 minutes

Comment: Then why does `{{''==undefined}}` result in `false`?

Comment: @NickA operation are executed and boolean is converted to a string value.

Comment: Sure ? Cause {{ blabla == undefined }} (suppose blabla as undefined) output true

Comment: @lin if operations are executed prior to the conversion then why does `{{undefined + 10}}` not result in the `undefined+10` occuring first?

Comment: @NickA, because nothing's equal to `undefined`, instead of two `undefined`'s

Comment: Seems logic. Recommended operators for this could be == or === ?

Comment: @Zooly, `==` is used to compare the values of two variables. `===` is used to compare values and also the types.

Comment: Yes I know. Is undefined considered as a type ? I'm talking about logic operators with data-binding, not in pure JS

Comment: @Zooly, the type of undefined is also `undefined`. You can choose both.

Comment: Why then `{{'' == +Infinity}}` is evaluated to `true`? And in the same time `{{'' == +(1/0)}}` returns `false`.

Comment: `{{''==undefined}}`- that returns `false` because the first step is to get the result of `expression` and then `display` the result. ``{{model+ 10}} and model is undefined - In this case it is applied the `Value stabilization algorithm`.  Compiler adds an interpolateDirective to the node and registers watches on the computed interpolation function, which will update the corresponding text nodes or attribute values as part of the normal digest cycle.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash, `'' == +Infinity` is evaluated to `false`, not `true`. The `type` of the `Infinity` is number.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai then why [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1fdzoHJXV2ICHIAeWuCy?p=preview) I see `true`? If you say it is evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @StanislavKvitash, I evaluated with `angular 1.0` version.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai, looks like this was somehow changed in `1.4`. Seems weird anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

To explain by referencing AngularJS code, this is the magic:

```
function plusFn(l, r) {
  if (typeof l === 'undefined') return r;
  if (typeof r === 'undefined') return l;
  return l + r;
}
```

If you have a "plus" expression, this function is parsed into your template.

The expression replacement is invoked by the Parser.parse (angular.js:16155) or parse.js:1646 (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/87a586eb9a23cfd0d0bb681cc778b4b8e5c8451d/src/ng/parse.js#L1646).

Comment: What is `angular if`?

Comment: Ok found it here (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/87a586eb9a23cfd0d0bb681cc778b4b8e5c8451d/src/ng/parse.js#L614). Interesting! Have to find where it's called

Comment: see this line: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/87a586eb9a23cfd0d0bb681cc778b4b8e5c8451d/src/ng/parse.js#L848

this is where the string function "return plus(undefined,10)" gets evaluated.